# Suppose $Gal(K/Q)$ is the symmetric group $S_{n}$ with $n>2$. Show that if $n\geq 4$, then the $nth$ power of the roof of $f$ is not rational

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This is a question from Lang's Algebra Chapter $VI$ $Q10.

Let $f(x)\in Q[x]$ be a polynomial of degree n, and let $K$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $Q$. Suppose that $Gal(K/Q)$ is the symmetric group $S_{n}$ with $n>2$.

$(a)$ show that $f$ is irreducible over $Q$

$(b)$ If $a$ is a root of $f$, show that the only automorphism of $Q(a)$ is the idenity.

$(c)$ If $n\geq 4$, show that $a^{n} \notin Q$.

I have shown the part $(b)$, but I am having trouble in $(a)$ and $(c)$. For $(a)$, I tried to assume that $f$ is reducible but I failed.

Any hints and detailed explanations are really really appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A)$ Since $K$ is galois over $Q$, $[K:Q] =  |Gal(K/Q)| = n!$

Since $f(x)$ is of degree $n$; there are obviously $n$ roots, $a_1, ... , a_n$.  Suppose $f$ is reducible.  Then $[Q(a_1) :Q] < n$.  Therefore [$K:Q] < n!$ and this is a contradiction with the statement above.

$C)$ Since $f$ is irreducible $[Q(a):Q] = n$.  If $a^n \in Q$, then $x^n - a^n$ would be a degree $n$ polynomial that contains $a$ as a root. This implies $f(x) = x^n - a^n$.  You don't have to search too deeply in chapter $6$ of Lang to see that the roots of $x^n - a^n$ are $\rho^i a$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ where $\rho$ is a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity.  Hence the splitting field of $x^n - a^n$ is $Q(\rho, a)$.  You also don't need to search to deeply in Lang to see that $[Q(\rho):Q] = \phi(n)$ where $\phi$ is the Euler function.  Therefore, $[Q(\rho,a):Q] =[Q(\rho,a):Q(\rho)] [Q(\rho):Q]  \leq n \phi(n)$.

It's trivial to see that $n \phi(n) < n!$ and this is a contradiction.

Comment: I am sorry that I could not see why $f$ is irreducible...... Also, for $c)$, I tried to prove $x^{n}-a^{n}$ is irreducible over $Q$, and then we can identify $f(x)$ with it, but I don't know how to do it. I think it must deal with the properties of $S_{n}$, but I don't know how to do it. Would you mind being more specific? Thank you so much

Comment: You have a slight misunderstanding for part C.  You're given that $f(x)$ is irreducible by part $A$. Therefore it is the minimal (degree)  polynomial over $Q$ that contains $a$ as a root.  We are now assuming that $a^n \in Q$ and this implies that $x^n - a^n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ which contains $a$ as a root.  So it must be equal to $f(x)$  This is why you know that $x^n - a^n$ is irreducible.

Comment: Oh! I see. I will try to think about the splitting field and come back! Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry but why $[Q(a_{1}):Q]< n$ implies $[K:Q]< n!$ ?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to analyze the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $Q$ and conclude that degree over $Q$ is $n!$

Comment: $[Q(a_1,a_2):Q] = [Q(a_1,a_2):Q(a_1)] [Q(a_1):Q] < n (n-1)$ and so on ...

Comment: I am sorry... Could you explain why $n\phi (n)<n!$?